# date to factor creating NAs

Tags: r

Why is this returning NA? I'd like to use `factor` to order dates in order to plot them.

```
 factor(today(), levels = today())
[1] <NA>
Levels: 2019-07-01
```

Comment: Do you mean `factor(today(), labels = today())`?

Comment: No (I don't think), I want to use `levels` to order the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "levels" argument expects character data. However, Date data have underlying numerical representations. So specifying:

```
factor(today(), levels = today())
```

Creates an invalid label for the data. It is equivalent to saying that you want the levels of the factor to include the number 18,708.

Explicitly specifying character data for the "levels" argument produces the expected result:

```
factor(today(), levels = as.character(today()))
[1] 2019-07-01
Levels: 2019-07-01
```

Date data are numeric and therefore inherently ordered. But if you wanted to convert these to factor first, be sure to specify the `ordered = TRUE` argument.